# TextFieldValue has inconsistent behavior setting cursor to end of text

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

The desired behavior that I want is for the cursor to be forced to the end of the text. The code works on two of the four devices of tried it on. Three virtual and one physical device. It's two virtual devices that don't work. Of the two that don't work you can't input more than one character. All devices are at API 34.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun categoryText(
    spacer: Dp,
    viewModel: CategoryTextViewModel = hiltViewModel()
): String {

    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val categoryText by viewModel.categoryText.collectAsState()
    val uniqueCategoryNames by viewModel.uniqueCategoryNames.collectAsState()

    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded })
    {

        viewModel.getUniqueCategoryNames()

        OutlinedTextField(
            value =  TextFieldValue(text = categoryText, selection = TextRange(categoryText.length)),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(start = spacer, end = spacer)
                .menuAnchor(),
            onValueChange = {
                viewModel.updateCategoryText(it.text)
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text),
            prefix = {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.category) + ": ",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer
                )
            },
        )

        ExposedDropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
        ) {
            uniqueCategoryNames.forEach { categoryNames ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    onClick = {
                        expanded = false
                        viewModel.updateCategoryText(categoryNames)
                    },
                    text = { Text(text = categoryNames) })
            }
        }
    }
    return categoryText
}


@HiltViewModel
class CategoryTextViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val expenseRepository: ExpenseRepository
): ViewModel(){

    private val _categoryText = MutableStateFlow("")
    val categoryText: StateFlow<String> = _categoryText.asStateFlow()

    fun updateCategoryText(newText: String) {
        _categoryText.value = newText
    }

    private val _uniqueCategoryNames = MutableStateFlow<List<String>>(emptyList())
    val uniqueCategoryNames: StateFlow<List<String>> = _uniqueCategoryNames.asStateFlow()

    fun getUniqueCategoryNames() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val uniqueCategoryNames = expenseRepository.getUniqueCategoryNames()
            val currentCategoryText = categoryText.value
            val sortedUniqueCategoryNames = uniqueCategoryNames
                .filter { it.startsWith(currentCategoryText, ignoreCase = true) }
                .sorted()

            _uniqueCategoryNames.value = sortedUniqueCategoryNames
        }
    }
}
```

The code works flawless on my physical device, but I'm confused why it won't work on the two Pixel virtual devices. The Pixel 7 virtual device works, but the Pixel and Pixel tablet only let me input one character.